# How does wake-on-lan works?

Tags: remote-desktop

Someone told me about wake-on-lan options in bios and it sounds great.
It would be kinda cool if I can turn my computer from office when it happens that I forgot to turn it on before I go to work so later on I could use teamviewer or what ever.
Can someone help me with this in details cause I never done this before?

Comment: Basically, you can have another system on the same network send a WOL packet to a powered-off computer with WOL turned on, and the system will then power on.  You can't WOL over the internet directly, there would have to be a system on that network powered on and accessible via the Internet that can send a WOL to the system you want turned on.  Some home routers can do this (and they'll generally be always turned on and able to be accessed remotely by design), or some such routers can be flashed to DD-WRT/OpenWRT that can do this.

Comment: I've looked into WOL myself before and it's far less useful than one would expect.  The "same broadcast domain" requirement makes it inconvenient in many circumstances (like all of them I find myself wanting WOL for).

Answer (score 0):

quite broad explanation is on:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN